# How can I add information to tooltips in shiny/leaflet using tm_fill?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

I've created an interactive map using shiny and leaflet: https://iseak.shinyapps.io/Mapa/

Currently, when you hover over the map the tooltip shows the name of the area. I can change it so that instead of the name of the area, another variable (e.g. the numeric value that colors the map) is shown, but I haven't been able to show both at the same time. I can only seem to do that when you **click** on the map and a popup shows up.

I'd like to be able to display both the area name & numeric value that colors the map when you hover over the area, not just upon clicking. Is there an easy way to do that?

The portion of my code that creates the map is pretty simple:

```
output$map = renderLeaflet({
      
      tm <- tm_shape(subsetData()) +
            tm_fill(selvar(),
                    palette=colores(),
                    alpha=0.95,
                    breaks=breaks(),
                    id="Zona", #Mouseover 
                    popup.vars=c(" "=selvar()), #Popups on click 
                    popup.format=list(digits=2),
                    legend.show = F,
                    labels=c(" "=selvar())
             ) + 
            tm_borders() 
            tmap_options(basemaps = "CartoDB.Positron")
```

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: One idea is to create a new column in your data (what you have in `subsetData()`) that is the area name `paste`d with the numeric value you wish to add, then include the new column name in `id` (which is used to determine what info to show on hover/mouseover).

Comment: Thanks, I'd been trying to do that but I'm finding it difficult and I wouldn't be able to style it via CSS differently (one column in each row of the tooltip, one bolded...)